# How to implement a bundle analyzer with nextjs and nrwl-nx?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I try to implement a bundle analyzer with nextjs and nrwl-nx. I tried to use @next/bundle-analyzer. But it does not work. How can I implement it successfully with latest NX monorepo with next.js app in module.exports = withNx(nextConfig)?

Could somebody please provide code snippets?

I tried many options to implement it in next.config.json but I always receive error messages during build. For example I tried:

- `module.exports = withNx( withBundleAnalyzer({ // Next.js configuration options // ... }) );`
- `module.exports = withNx(nextConfig).withBundleAnalyzer({ enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true', });`
- `module.exports = withNx({ // Next.js configuration options // ... })(withBundleAnalyzer);`
- `module.exports = withNx({ // Next.js configuration options // ... }).withBundleAnalyzer({ enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true', });`

This are just some examples. In each I also tried with `future: { webpack5: true, // Enable webpack 5 }`. Still, no success story at all.
Could somebody please provide code snippets? Or a solution to enable bundle analyzing like with @next/bundle-analyzer with my nx monorepo with an next.js app?